# sequelize migration with transactions not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

```
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    const transaction = await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction();
    try {
      await queryInterface.addColumn(
        'Person',
        'petName',
        {
          type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        { transaction }
      );
      await queryInterface.addColumn(
        'Personasfasfasfasf',
        'petAge',
        {
          type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
        {transaction}
      );
      await transaction.commit();
    } catch (err) {
      await transaction.rollback();
      throw err;
    }
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    const transaction = await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction();
    try {
      await queryInterface.removeColumn('Person', 'petName', { transaction });
      await queryInterface.removeColumn('Person', 'petAge', { transaction });
      await transaction.commit();
    } catch (err) {
      await transaction.rollback();
      throw err;
    }
  }
};
```

I have Person table in my database. I am using mysql database.

I have introduced a table name error and I expect my migration to rollback, the code flow does go to catch blow but petName column is created in Person Table.

This is a sample from sequelize documentation can anyone help me with this? It does not work with transactions.

Even if I remove transaction.commit(); petName column is added to Person table.

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/discussions/16082

mysql does not support transactions for DDL.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour and not related to Sequelize, but a "limitation" of MySQL. Basically, there are some statements that cannot be rolled back, mostly DDL statements.

Taken from the MySQL documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html